# Redirect All the External Links Except Which I Don't Want To Redirect

Tags: jquery, http, https, httpwebrequest

Yesterday I asked the similar question, so I get to know how to redirects all the external links to my home page.

```
// when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // iterate over all the anchor tags
    $("a").each(function() {
        // if the current link's href doesn't already contain 'www.kownleg.com'
        if (this.href.indexOf('www.kownleg.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.kownleg.com';
        }
    });
});
```

But now I want to exclude all the links which I don't want to redirect to my home page, like facebook.com & twitter.com, I tried to make another condition for the links which I don't want to redirect, but its not working. Then I tried to change `indexOf()` with `text()` but still not working.

---

Here is two codings which I tried, but I failed

```
// when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // iterate over all the anchor tags
    $("a").each(function() {
        // if the current link's href doesn't already contain 'www.kownleg.com'
        if (this.href.indexOf('www.kownleg.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.kownleg.com';
        }
        if (this.href.indexOf('www.facebook.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.facebook.com';
        }
        if (this.href.indexOf('www.twitter.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.twitter.com';
        }
    });
});
```

Another One:

```
// when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // iterate over all the anchor tags
    $("a").each(function() {
        // if the current link's href doesn't already contain 'www.kownleg.com'
        if (this.href.indexOf('www.kownleg.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.kownleg.com';
        }
        if (this.href.text('www.facebook.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.facebook.com';
        }
        if (this.href.text('www.twitter.com') === -1) {
            // change current link to home page
            this.href = 'http://www.twitter.com';
        }
    });
});
```

And all the similar possibilities... but still not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it all around an if statement:

```
if(
    (this.href.indexOf('www.twitter.com')  !== -1) ||
    (this.href.indexOf('www.kownleg.com')  !== -1) ||
    (this.href.indexOf('www.facebook.com') !== -1)
  ){
  //do what you were doing.
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
In the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allowed_links_array = [
    "www.kownleg.com",
    "www.twitter.com",
    "www.facebook.com"
  ];
  var replacement = [
    "http://www.kownleg.com",
    "http://www.twitter.com",
    "http://www.facebook.com"
  ];
  // iterate over all the anchor tags
  $("a").each(function() {
    var index;
    //get the index of the last part of the href attribute after the /
    index = jQuery.inArray(
      this.href.split('/')[this.href.split('/').length - 1],
      allowed_links_array
    );
    //if the link is in the allowed_links_array then set the href to the right link
    if(index !== -1){
      this.href = replacement[index];
    }
  });
});
```

[working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywM4Ukx8pFHj4Ve4goPJ?p=preview) you can inspect the anchor tags to see the href changed.
I hope this is what you'r looking for.

Comment: its not working dude, u didnt put the link other than kownleg.com, facebook & twitter, I put blogger.com in ur script which u made, but its not working... check it
http://plnkr.co/edit/aAYuiXQadmIukpFIwoT0

Comment: it's working you need always to add the allowed url to the both arrays in the scripts.js file in the same index, [check this](http://plnkr.co/edit/2NBAr2ZmgtvNKoMzvkyt?p=preview).